# make: implicit rule, (tail-)recursively applied?

Tags: makefile

I have a calculation `A.N` where each step depends on the previous step `A.N-1` (except the first step) as well as another sequential calculation result, `B.N`.  I'd like to express this relation in a make file:

```
A.001: calc.script B.001
  $^ > $@

A.%: calc.script B.% A.(%-1) # (%-1) is pseudocode for idea
  $^ > $@
```

I can get the second rule to work for `A.002`, but it won't work for `A.003`.  The approach I used for the pseudocode part above is:

```
# ... A.001 rule
define dec = $(shell echo $(1)-1|bc|xargs printf '%03d') # want 3 digit #s
.SECONDEXPANSION:
A.%: calc.script B.% A.$$(call dec,$$*)
  $$^ > $$@
```

Is there language support for this kind of approach?  I'm looking at just have having a `$(foreach ..., $(eval $(call ...)))` construct to build the rules, but I'd prefer a recursive approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules):

```
"No single implicit rule can appear more than once in a chain."
```

This is a feature, not a bug. The kind of recursion you want is possible in Make, but Make isn't really suited to it.

Comment: Got it - I had been looking for that clear statement, as I saw hints elsewhere that was the behavior, but couldn't find it.  Thanks - I'll just use a loop to construct the rules, since I have a well-defined final index.